# Why doesn't "coverage.py run -a" always increase my code coverage percent?

Tags: coverage.py

I have a GUI application that I am trying to determine what is being used and what isn't. I have a number of test suites that have to be run manually to test the user interface portions. Sometimes I run the same file a couple of times with "coverage.py run file_name -a" and do different actions each time to check different interface tools. I would expect that each time I ran with the -a argument, I could only *increase* the code covered line count by coverage.py (at least unless new files are pulled in). However, sometimes it gives lower code coverage after an additional run - what could be causing this?

I am not editing source between runs and no new files are being pulled in as far as I can tell. I am using coverage.py version 3.5.1.

Comment: I can confirm that this is not being caused by new files being added - I have observed a file whose total statement count stays the same while the missing line count increases.

Answer (score 0):

That sounds odd indeed.  If you can provide source code and a list of steps to reproduce the problem, I'd like to take a look at it: you can create a ticket for it here: https://bitbucket.org/ned/coveragepy/issues

Comment: Unfortunately the source code is large and proprietary, so I won't be able to share it. I'll try to come up with a smaller test case, but I'm not sure I'll be able to. (Other than this though, coverage.py is great - thanks!)